# Servidor de Banco de dados no Azure

Tags: .net, asp.net, microsoft-azure

Criei um servidor de banco de dados no Azure nos EUA.
Antes o meu banco de dados ficava na Locaweb. No Azure ficou mais lenta as consultas ao banco. Tentei criar um servidor aqui no Brasil, aparece a opção de criação, mas ao clicar em criar mostrar uma mensagem de erro , dizendo que não está disponível.
Será que a distância do servidor do banco pode impactar significamente a minha aplicação ?
Como liberar a criação de um servidor de banco do Azure aqui no Brasil ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dizer que a distância não impacta na *perfomance* seria errado.
Porém, o quanto impacta?**

Um tempo de resposta padrão de um servidor na *locaweb costuma ser de 30ms* contra *140ms do Azure*.

Se sua consulta está demorando 3 segundos, 110 milissegundos não representa nenhuma diferença significativa.

Acredito que pode ser o padrão SQL fraco que você pegou no Azure, existem diversos 'pacotes' cada um com desempenho diferente e preços diferentes.

A vantagem do Azure é que ele tem diversos monitores de desempenho pré configurados, que podem lhe auxiliar na identificação de gargalos.

Além de ser um cloud de verdade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Dorathoto  , Meu padrão é o SO Standard. Você considera ele bom ? Consegui criar o servidor aqui no Brasil, é só desmarca a atualização V12 no momento da criação.

Comment: sinceramente não sou indicado para falar sobre Azure, só tenho uma instancia lá, com o Padrão também..acho razoavel, nada de espetacular o desempenho, se bem que locaweb eu sempre achei péssimo..rs

Answer (score 1):

O Correto quando vc tem acesso a máquina do SQL é rodar a calculadora de DTU assim podendo estimar qual é o tamanho do SQL A ser contratado.

OBS: imaginando que seja SQL sobre serviço do Azure.

**Calculadora DTU**
http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/

Claro que na locaweb você não conseguirá estimar os DTU.

Recomendo utilizar o Pool Elastic do SQL no Azure, assim a cada 80% de carga ele replica um novo servidor horizontalmente (horizontalmente pq será igual a config do seu primeiro servidor)

E Caso ainda preciso poderá escalar ele verticalmente (mudando a config da maquina)

O Scaling vertical o serviço do sql é pausado, no horizontal não.

Lembrando que o custo do Azure tende a ser superior a Localweb, porém conta com milhares de recursos a mais.
https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/calculator/